# Description of the Syntax within System.Data.DataTable.Compute

Tags: c#, datatable, string-formatting

First I have following numbers which I convert in a string.

```
decimal numberA = 1.0M;
decimal numberB = 2.0M;
string numberAString = numberA.ToString(); // numberAString = 1,0
string numberBString = numberB.ToString(); // numberBString = 2,0
```

So far so good `ToString()` uses the current culture, which is on my system `de-CH` and the decimal separator is a coma.

Then I create a formula expression and compute the formula with the Method `System.Data.DataTable.Compute`

```
// create formula expression
string formulaExpression = "{0} + {1}";
string formula = string.Format(formulaExpression, numberAString, numberBString); 
// formula = 1,0 + 2,0

// compute formula
object result;
result = new System.Data.DataTable().Compute(formula, filter:string.Empty);
```

I got a `System.Data.SyntaxErrorException` when I run this code. I recognized, that the `Compute` method is not satisfy with the coma delimiter. When I convert the decimal value with `.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` [the culture-independent language](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) english is used and therefore the point delimiter for the string representation of the decimal value is used and it works fine.

My question is, what is the name of this Syntax that I can use as expression within the `System.Data.DataTable.Compute` Method and where is this Syntax respectively the allowed operators and functions described? [The MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) gives me not so much information about this Syntax.

Comment: MSDN documentation also says: `For rules on creating expressions for both parameters (expression, filter), see the DataColumn.Expression property.` :)

Comment: Thanks for your hint.

Answer (score 0):

The [Expression Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is described in the MSDN Documentation of the Property `System.Data.DataColumn.Expression`.

You can find this [hint at the bottom of the section remarks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from the MSDN documention of `System.Data.DataTable.Compute`.

Nice to know is the following statement within the section "Parsing Literal Expressions" within the Documentation of the Expression Syntax.

> All literal expressions must be expressed in the invariant culture locale. When DataSet parses and converts literal expressions, it always uses the invariant culture, not the current culture.

So in my case I have to convert the decimals `numberA` and `numberB` with following `ToString` overload to consider the invariant culture locale.

```
string numberAString = numberA.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 
// numberAString = 1.0
string numberBString = numberB.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 
// numberBString = 2.0
```

A little bit special in my case is the circumstance that I run in a known [Windows 8.1 Bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/814496/incorrect-cultureinfo-definition-for-de-ch-it-ch-fr-ch-de-li-in-win8-1). For some reason the decimal delimiter is for the culture `de-CH` a coma. This is wrong. Correct would be a point as decimal delimiter character.  For details refer this [Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Hindu.E2.80.93Arabic_numeral_system).